# Compromised Ubuntu? Weird unauthorised iso file downloads and download attempts

Tags: security, iso, malware, hacking

I noticed 2 failed attempts at downloading an iso file in my Downloads, that were attempted without my knowing. It happened while I was using the computer (attempt time 10:06, screenshot 1). The strangest thing is that later they appeared above all other (attempt time 10:24, screenshot 2).

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

File: *ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso*.
Source: *koyanet.lv*.

Also I found a *Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-37-1.7.iso*, that I haven't downloaded in my Downloads.

Could my Ubuntu be compromised? What can an iso file do?

Comment: If you did not download the file and it is there then it seems YES your system is hacked.

Comment: On a closer look this is the file you say you have. ubuntu-22.04.-adm64.iso No such file it is amd not adm.

Comment: No, I just specified the name of the file. I do have iso images, but I haven't downloaded this one, also not the Fedora image. Mine are a lot older, so I am pretty sure it wasn't me

Comment: I was pointing out it is not a valid file name.

Comment: Oh, sorry, left 'desktop' out. Also, I do have the same iso file, but downloaded in summer 2022.

Answer (score 0):

The `koyanet.lv` mirror is an [official Latvian mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.koyanet.lv-release).

[image]

So you somehow downloaded the ISO files from this mirror - nothing to worry about for that particular ISO file.

Comment: I noticed, that the time of the attempt changes whenever I turn on the computer and then the browser. However, not when I turn the WiFi off and on and then reconnect to the network again.
Can it be some kind of a past failed attempt, that just repeats itself upon restarting?

Comment: @GracePine that sounds very likely - I know for sure that some browsers will retry downloads if they have been disconnected.

Comment: Thank you very much!